# Visual Studio Code check require statements

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

Having refactored the filenames and folder structure of various of Node.js applications, I have found it incredibly time consuming to manually fix all relative require statement paths.

```
const myRequire = require('../../my-require')
```

May become

```
const myRequire = require('./my-require')
```

Could Visual Studio Code underline relative require statements that it suspects are incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [eslint plugin for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint)

Configure the project to use [eslint](http://eslint.org/) and [eslint-plugin-require-path-exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-require-path-exists).

Visual Studio Code will show all eslint errors within the editor, including require statements that cannot be resolved.